# Salvar entidades relacionadas com cakephp-3

Tags: php, cakephp, mvc, cakephp-3

não entendo porque entidades relacionadas não está funcionando com cakephp, por exemplo: Eu tenho uma entidade empresa, e essa empresa tem um usuário. Na minha view, os values da empresa coloco corretamente [$empresa->cnpj] e os values para usuário, coloco através do relacionamento [$empresa->usuario->nome], porém, ao salvar os dados, não são persistidos. Segue meu controller.

```
public function add()
{
    $empresa = $this->Empresas->newEntity();
    $tableUser = TableRegistry::get("Users");
    $user = $tableUser->newEntity();
    $empresa->user = $user;
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $empresa = $this->Empresas->patchEntity($empresa, $this->request->data, ['associated' => ['Users.User']]);
        if ($this->Empresas->save($empresa,['associated' => ['User']])) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('Sua empresa foi cadastrada com sucesso!'));
            return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Public', 'action' => 'boasvindas']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__("Ohh não! Houve um problema, por favor comunique-nos o quanto antes."));
        }
    }
    $users = $this->Empresas->Users->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('empresa', 'users'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['empresa']);
}
```

Não sei o $this->Empresas->save($empresa,['associated' => ['User']]) está errado. Gostaria de uma ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

O `['associated' => ['User']]` precisa ser minusculo.

Tente assim:

```
$empresa = $this->Empresas->patchEntity($empresa, $this->request->data, ['associated' => ['user']]);
```

Lembrando que no formulário também precisa ser minusculo o nome dos campos associados:

```
echo $this->Form->input('user.0.id');
echo $this->Form->input('user.0.name');
echo $this->Form->input('user.1.id');
echo $this->Form->input('user.1.name');
```

Comment: Opa, obrigado amigo.